# Question about spectral theorem for compact operators

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory, compact-operators

Consider the following fragment:

[image]

Questions:

(1) Does every non-zero eigenvalue occur in the $\{\lambda_i: i =1, 2, \dots\}$?

(2) Why if $\lambda \ne 0$ is the eigenspace of $\lambda$ finite dimensional? I can see this must be the case if $(1)$ is true.

Comment: (1) yes, (2) because of compactness

Comment: Why is $(1)$ yes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) this is the statement of the spectral theorem. Assume one eigenvalue $\tilde \lambda$ is missing in the enumeration in the theorem. Then the associated eigenvector $\tilde v$ is orthogonal to all the other eigenvectors that are used in the spectral theorem. This implies
$\tilde v \in \ker T^{\perp\perp}=\ker T$. Hence $\tilde \lambda=0$, contradiction.

Comment: Thanks! And can you expand on $(2)$ as well?

Comment: (2) is a basic properties of compact operators: eigenspaces to non-zero eigenvalues are finite-dimensional.

Comment: Alright, thanks for all the help!

Comment: Regarding (2), notice that the unit ball of the eigenspace $E_\lambda$ is scaled by $\lambda$ under $T$.  Therefore the
ball of radius $\lambda$ in $E_\lambda$ is contained in the image under $T$ of the unit ball of $\mathscr H$, which is
relatively compact.  This implies that ball of radius $\lambda$ in $E_\lambda$ is relatively compact, but this can only
happen in a finite dimensional space!